# Running .NET Console Docker image in Ubuntu failing

Tags: c#, .net, docker

Create a docker image for a .NET Console application. But when trying to run the image, its throwing error.

Following section contains the Dockerfile content,

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0
COPY bin/Release/net6.0/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MySampleApplication.dll"]`
```

Following is the error that I get while trying to run the docker image,

```
docker run collector

You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: /MySampleApplication.dll
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '6.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/share/dotnet/
No frameworks were found.

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=6.0.0&arch=x64&rid=debian.11-x64`
```

Tried installing .NET sdk and runtime environment in Ubuntu, but still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your app might run from the console, but in MS terminology, it's not a console app. You get a message saying `Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '6.0.0' (x64)` and that tells us that it's an ASP.NET application. ASP.NET is not included in the `console` image, but it *is* included in the `aspnet` image.

So change your Dockerfile to

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
COPY bin/Release/net6.0/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MySampleApplication.dll"]
```

When you run it, you'll need to map port 80 to a host port to be able to talk to the application. So your `docker run` command will look something like

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 collector
```

You should then be able to reach the application on `http://localhost:8080/` from the host.

Comment: Hi Hans, our application is not at all a console application. Actually one of the dependencies works with ASP.NET Core package. Maybe that is why this Microsoft.AspNetCore.App has been added. Can that be the case?